# iOS 8 UITableView with static cells not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I've created this Table View Controller in Storyboard. It look like this and uses **UITableViewController**. I don't have wired up anything yet, and I don't have written any code that has something to do with that VC. Content is set to **Static Cells**.

[image]

But if I run the App it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like the UITableView just disappears.

**If change content to Dynamically the table view is shown** (the background is not black but gray).

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @BlackM I remember having had something messed up in Interface Builder, like two table views or wrong constraints but I cannot remember exactly. Sorry, I can’t help you more.

Comment: My problem was that I accidentally connected the TableView with the navigation controller using the "push" option instead of the "root view controller"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The problem is not the static cell but that you connected `Navigation Controller` with the wrong connection for the root view controller. In my case I connected the `Navigation Controller` with **"push"** instead of **"root view controller"** in `Storyboard`'s `Segue`.